# Sudoku algorithm, brute force

Tags: algorithm, sudoku, brute-force

Iam trying to solve a sudoku board with a brute force algorithm, I cant really get this algorithm work correctly.

There is created a object for each row, column and box that contains all squares(cells) that belongs to the actually column, square and row, this is used in legalValue() to check if value can be placed in the cell.

I cant find the structure that make the algorithm to work.

```
    boolean setNumberMeAndTheRest(Board board) {


    if(getNext() == null) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= board.getDimension(); i++) {
            if(legalValue(i)) {
                setValue(i);
            }
        }
        board.saveSolution();
    } else {
        if(this instanceof DefinedSquare) {
            getNext().setNumberMeAndTheRest(board);

        } else {
            for(int i = 1; i <= board.getDimension(); i++) {
                if(legalValue(i)) {
                    setValue(i);

                    if(getNext().setNumberMeAndTheRest(board)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        setValue(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is legalValue(int i);

```
/**
 * Checks if value is legal in box, row and column.
 * @param value to check.
 * @return true if value is legal, else false.
 */
boolean legalValue(int value) {
    if(box.legalValue(value) && row.legalValue(value) && columne.legalValue(value)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```
**4x4 Sudoku board INPUT**

0 2 | 1 3
0 0 | 0 4
---------
0 0 | 0 1
0 4 | 3 2

**Expected OUTPUT**

4 2 | 1 3
3 1 | 2 4
---------
2 3 | 4 1
1 4 | 3 2

**Actually OUTPUT**

4 2 | 1 3
2 4 | 3 4
---------
3 0 | 0 1
0 4 | 3 2
```

---

Added resetting of board

```
boolean setNumberMeAndTheRest(Board board) {

    Board original = board;

    if(getNext() == null) { 
        for(int i = 1; i <= board.getDimension(); i++) {
            if(legalValue(i)) {
                setValue(i);
            }
        }
        board.saveSolution();

    } else {
        if(this instanceof DefinedSquare) {
            getNext().setNumberMeAndTheRest(board);

        } else {
            for(int i = 1; i <= board.getDimension(); i++) {
                if(legalValue(i)) {
                    setValue(i);

                    if(getNext().setNumberMeAndTheRest(board)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        setValue(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            board = original;
            return false;
        }
    }
    board = original;
    return false;
}
```

Her is a solution, after a long time :D

```
boolean setNumberMeAndTheRest(Board board) {

    if(next == null) {
        board.saveSolution();
        return true;
    }

    if(this instanceof DefinedSquare) {
        return next.setNumberMeAndTheRest(board);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= board.getDimension(); ++i) {
        if(legalValue(i)) {
            setValue(i);

            if(next.setNumberMeAndTheRest(board)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    setValue(0);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean you can't get it to work? What's the error?

Comment: The output is like this, there is zeroes in the last row.561733
242567
624364
265642
756350
300102

Comment: a. comment your code so we can tell what you're doing  b. provide sample inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs  c. use a 3x3 or 4x4 to test with, much easier to trace than 6x6

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Have done b and c, some a.

Comment: You need to unset the value before returning `false`. (You tried to fill the cell, you failed, leave the cell exactly as you've got it). Also, the "object-oriented" approach doesn't buy anything here except complications. A simple 2D array of numbers will do the job just fine.

Comment: I now see that legalValue(int value) dosent check the box, thats now corrected, actually the same output. I do not understand where or how to unset the value, can you please show me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Brute force Sudoku algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193330/brute-force-sudoku-algorithm)

Comment: Yep, but no more answers on the other

Comment: What operation removes a number from the cell? How should I know? You have never used such operation, nor exposed the internals of your class.

Comment: How come you get a **5** in a 4×4 sudoku?

Comment: You seem to use `this instanceof DefinedSquare` as a test for an empty square. I wonder how the result of this check ever changes.

Comment: 5 is typos, corrected. I does not have a function or something outside this algorithm for changing values. I asked this question because I dont know what I do, or how to write the algorithm, I'm confused :(

Comment: I final did find a solution, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean setNumberMeAndTheRest(Board board) {

  // make a copy of the original board
  Board original = board;
```

then every time you return false, you also need to reset the board to its original state

```
board = original;
return false;
```

Comment: I believe that this does nothing, because the output is still the same.

Comment: did you reset the board to the original state each time you return false?

Comment: Yep. I only return false two places in the algorithm, see my edit.

Comment: Dunno.  If I were you I'd try a 2x2 or 3x3 and just go through the entire algorithm step-by-step in the debugger until you find it.

Comment: Me neither, I'm blind in the code

Comment: I final did find a solution, see my edit.